# How can I eject my app from expo to bare react native code

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, development-environment

I make an app using expo cli and now I want it to eject to react native. I used the command 'expo eject' to eject the app. when I give npm run android, the app is not build successfully and there are lot of errors. I tried solving them but none of the solution worked for me.

```
> delivery-app-fe@1.0.0 android D:\projects\delivery-app-fe
```

> react-native run-android

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1335 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :app

Installing unimodules:
unimodules-core@5.3.0 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules@unimodules\core
unimodules-react-native-adapter@5.4.0 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules@unimodules\react-native-adapter
expo-app-auth@9.1.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-app-auth
expo-constants@9.1.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-constants
expo-error-recovery@1.2.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-error-recovery
expo-file-system@9.0.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-file-system
expo-font@8.2.2 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-font
expo-image-loader@1.1.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-image-loader
expo-keep-awake@8.2.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-keep-awake
expo-linear-gradient@8.2.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-linear-gradient
expo-location@8.2.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-location
expo-permissions@9.0.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-permissions
expo-splash-screen@0.5.0 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo\node_modules\expo-splash-screen
expo-sqlite@8.2.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-sqlite
expo-updates@0.2.14 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-updates
unimodules-app-loader@1.2.0 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\unimodules-app-loader
unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface@5.2.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface
unimodules-camera-interface@5.2.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\unimodules-camera-interface
unimodules-constants-interface@5.2.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\unimodules-constants-interface
unimodules-face-detector-interface@5.2.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\unimodules-face-detector-interface
unimodules-file-system-interface@5.2.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\unimodules-file-system-interface
unimodules-font-interface@5.2.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\unimodules-font-interface
unimodules-image-loader-interface@5.2.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\unimodules-image-loader-interface
unimodules-permissions-interface@5.2.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\unimodules-permissions-interface
unimodules-sensors-interface@5.2.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\unimodules-sensors-interface
unimodules-task-manager-interface@5.2.1 from D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\unimodules-task-manager-interface

Found some duplicated unimodule packages. Installed the ones with the highest version number.
Make sure following dependencies of your project are resolving to one specific version:
expo-splash-screen

> Task :unimodules-core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :expo-constants:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :expo-app-auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :expo-file-system:processDebugManifest
> D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-file-system\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:10:9-21:20 Warning:
> provider#expo.modules.filesystem.FileSystemFileProvider@android:authorities was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:10 to replace
> other declarations but no other declaration present

> Task :expo-file-system:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :expo-image-loader:compileDebugKotlin
> w: D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-image-loader\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\imageloader\ImageLoaderModule.kt: (
> 11, 42): 'SimpleTarget<Z : Any!>' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-image-loader\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\imageloader\ImageLoaderModule.kt: (
> 83, 22): 'SimpleTarget<Z : Any!>' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

> Task :expo-location:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :expo-sqlite:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :expo-updates:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Gradle may disable incremental compilation as the following annotation processors are not incremental: room-compiler-2.1.0.jar (andr
> oidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0).
> Consider setting the experimental feature flag android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true in the gradle.properties file to run
> annotation processing in a separate task and make compilation incremental.

> Task :react-native-community_async-storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-community_datetimepicker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build\kotlin\sessions

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
460 actionable tasks: 460 executed
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-constants\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\constants\ConstantsService.java use
s or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-app-auth\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\appauth\AppAuthModule.java uses unch
ecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-file-system\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\filesystem\FileSystemModule.java
uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-location\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\location\taskConsumers\GeofencingTas
kConsumer.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\expo-sqlite\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\sqlite\SQLiteModule.java uses unchecke
d or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules@react-native-community\async-storage\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity
asyncstorage\AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react
\RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\reanimated\NodesManager.j
ava uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\reanimated\NodesManager.j
ava uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
D:\projects\delivery-app-fe\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
Attribute data@scheme at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for  is
provided.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute data@scheme at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for  is provided.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to ge
  t full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 51s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environ
ment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! delivery-app-fe@1.0.0 android: `react-native run-android`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the delivery-app-fe@1.0.0 android script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\arihant\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-11-04T11_31_04_493Z-debug.log

D:\projects\delivery-app-fe>

Answer (score 1):

You should run 'expo eject' for ejecting then follow the steps defined in the below link:

See: https://docs.expo.io/expokit/expokit/